# Variance Reduction by conditioning: How to know over what variable to condition?

Tags: probability

I have a question related to variance reduction by conditioning. If I have to RV´s  $X$ and $Y$ with means $1$ and $2$ respectevely and  I want to approach the value of $P(X+Y \gt 4)$ by simulating. However, I´m not sure over what variable to condition when applying the variance reduction. I think it should be on the variable with greatest mean (e.g $Y$), but this is just by pure intuiton . Is there any way I can know how will I get the best result?

Comment: It depends on the distributions. The exact answer is found by just comparing the expression for variance under both choices.  Intuitively, in most cases I would expect that if $X$ has smaller _variance_ then it should be simulated instead of $Y$.   As an extreme example, if $X$ is deterministic and $Y$ is not, then "simulating" $X$ and using $Pr[X+Y>4|X=x]$ will give an estimate for $Pr[X+Y>4]$ that is _exact_ (with zero variance), while simulating the $Y$ variable will not give a zero variance estimate.  So the means $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ have nothing to do with it in this example.

Comment: I am assuming that if you choose to simulate $X$, you somehow have the ability to do it independently many times, and somehow have an exact formula for $g(x) = Pr[X+Y>4|X=x]$, in which case your estimate is just $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Ng(X_i)$, where $\{X_1, \ldots, X_N\}$ are the independent outcomes of your simulation of random variables with the same distribution as $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) Your insight about selecting the variable with the smaller variance is what I needed to know. So independent of the distribution, I would know that the variable that I should choose to condition on is the one with smaller variance. Am I right?

Comment: I doubt that is _always_ true. It is just a "rule of thumb" that happens to be true in the extreme example I gave, and also likely true in many examples. In general, if you define $g(x) = Pr[X+Y>4|X=x]$ and $f(y)=Pr[X+Y>4|Y=y]$, you need to compare $Var(g(X))$ and $Var(f(Y))$.

Comment: Ohhh ok. I was thinking of simulating the variables as exponencial independent variables (since I´m using them to get times). What should I check in this type of random variables to select the correct one in the variance reduction? Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: You need to compute the functions $g(x)$ and $f(y)$, and then compare the variances of $g(X)$ and $f(Y)$.  Since $E[g(X)]=E[f(Y)]$, you can just compare second moments.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Michael :) Really helped me out